# ¿Cómo usar el método Mid en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy programando un código personalizado para productos de un sistema de inventario. Este se forma a partir de la unión de los últimos 4 dígitos del código de barras del producto, la fecha y un autonumérico de 3 dígitos.

Ejemplo:

```
C. Barras:    785DEAD-987ED4632
Fecha:        01/08/2017
Autonumérico: 001

CÓDIGO:       463201082017001
```

Para esto quiero usar el método `Mid` (porque es el único que conozco) para cortar cadenas de texto. Pero al ubicarlo, me manda un error que no se reconoce ese método. Tal vez alguien que le halla pasado esto pueda ayudarme.

Mi código:

```
public string retKey(string bar, string date, string aut) {
     string tmp, keyRet;
     tmp = Mid(bar, bar.Length - 4, 4);//Aqui intento usar el Mid
     keyRet = tmp;
     tmp = date.Replace('/', '');
     keyRet = keyRet + tmp + aut;
     return keyRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Mid no lo reconoce por que es un método de Visual Basic y no de C#. Solo debes importar la Libreria `Microsoft.VisualBasic` a tu proyecto y listo funcionará...

puedes revisar la documentación: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8kyd8789(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Como bien dijo [@Michael](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/43012/18951), [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8kyd8789(v=vs.110).aspx) es una función de Visual Basic. Y, en efecto, puedes usarlo desde C#, incluyendo la librería `Microsoft.VisualBasic` en tu proyecto.

Pero, para poder usarlo correctamente, debes hacer algo más.

#### Strings.Mid

Como `Mid` está definido como una función estática de la clase [`Strings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings(v=vs.110).aspx), debes incluir la clase `Strings` en la sentencia.

Ejemplo:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

// ...

tmp = Strings.Mid(bar, bar.Length - 4, 4);
```

#### Static import

Si deseas usarlo igual como en VB, o sea, sin el `Strings.` en frente, puedes hacerlo con un *static import*.

Ejemplo:

```
using static Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings;

// ...

tmp = Mid(bar, bar.Length - 4, 4);
```

#### Corrigiendo el uso de Mid para devolver los 4 últimos caracteres

Una vez que logres usar `Mid`, te vas a dar cuenta que no lo estás usando correctamente.  La sentencia:

```
tmp = Mid(bar, bar.Length - 4, 4);
```

... no devuelve los últimos 4 caracteres de la cadena. Por ejemplo, con la cadena `785DEAD-987ED4632`, la sentencia te va a devolver `D463`, no `4632`.

Para devolver los 4 últimos caracteres, la sentencia correcta es:

```
tmp = Mid(bar, bar.Length - 3, 4);
```

... o simplemente:

```
tmp = Mid(bar, bar.Length - 3);
```

#### Una mejor alternativa: Right()

Si estás dispuesto a usar una de las funciones de VB, te sugiero que uses [`Right()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right(v=vs.110).aspx) en vez de [`Mid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8kyd8789(v=vs.110).aspx). Su uso es mucho mas sencillo para tu situación. Si quieres extraer los últimos 4 caracteres de la cadena, la sentencia es sencillamente:

```
using static Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings;

// ...

tmp = Right(bar, 4);
```

#### Alternativa sin usar Microsoft.VisualBasic

Y finalmente, si quieres hacer lo mismo sin depender de la librería `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, puedes usar [`String.Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) de esta manera:

```
tmp = bar.Substring(bar.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando C#, también puedes crearte un [método de Extensión](http://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Metodos-de-Extension-en-C.aspx).

Sería algo así:

```
namespace Bau.Extensors
{
    public static class StringExtensor
    {
      public static string Mid(this string strSource, int intFirst, int intLength)
      { if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSource))
            return "";
        else if (intFirst > strSource.Length)
            return "";
        else
            { if (intFirst + intLength > strSource.Length)
                intLength = strSource.Length - intFirst; 
              return strSource.Substring(intFirst, intLength);
            }
      }
   }
}
```

No olvides utilizar un `using Bau.Extensors` en las clases donde utilices el método de extensión.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una forma de trabajar lo que quieres en C#, dado que hay muchas funciones que hacen el trabajo que buscas y no necesariamente necesitas la función `Mid()`.

```
public string retKey(string bar, string date, string aut) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bar) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(date) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(aut)) {
    // Haz algo para alertar al usuario.
  }
  return (bar.Substring(bar.Length - 4) + date.Replace('/', '\0') + aut);
}
```

Donde:

- `string.Substring(int)`: Forma un nuevo `string` a partir de la posición que has pasado por parametro.
- El `if` ha sido sólo para validar que ninguna cadena haya pasado vacía a la función.
- El `date.Replace('/', '\0')` he puesto el `'\0'` dado que C# no admite literales vacías cuando se trata de caracteres.

De paso te dejo un fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ds4CXs :)